# Atomic presence check and lock file creation

Tags: c++, filesystems, locking, c++20

I'm writing a program that synchronizes the contents of directories on a disk. In order to prevent simultaneous access of several program instances to one directory, I create a lock file (or not necessarily a file, it could be a directory, for example). If, when accessing a directory, the program sees a lock file there, then this means that someone is already working with this directory and it will not work with this directory, but will wait until the lock file is deleted.

I am concerned about this question: it is theoretically possible for a situation where we check for the presence of a file on the disk and see that it is not there and create it ourselves, but in the time interval between checking and creating the file it was created by another instance of the program. As a result, the two programs are confident that they own the contents of the directory and will change it simultaneously without realizing it. This problem is described as [Time-of-check to time-of-use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) race condition.

How could this situation be eliminated? Or is this situation impossible?

I prefer do not use OS-specific functions for the solution, since the shared folder could be, for example, a WebDav network drive or something similar. It is better to use functions from the C++ standard library.

Several potential solutions have been found, but I'm not sure if these operations are atomic. Possible solutions:

```
 std::fopen with the "x" flag.
 std::filesystem::create_directory
 std::filesystem::rename
 std::filesystem::copy_file
```

Are these solutions atomic functions suitable for creating a lock file? Or is there some other better solution?

Comment: Unfortunately the standard doesn't provide any guarantees if multiple processes/threads act on the same file system object at all. It is blanket UB, see https://eel.is/c++draft/filesystems#fs.race.behavior-1. Even individual library calls that you list do not need to be atomic. So your answer needs to be system-specific to some degree at least.

Comment: (`std::fopen` is excluded from the above. It is not specified in the C++ standard, but the C standard instead.)

Comment: Yes if you first check and then create there is a race condition. If however you first create a unique_lock file and then check for the existence of other lock files its should be safe. If all other lock files are newer then yours (or there are no other lock files) you can proceed. Kind of think like getting a numbered ticket for a queue at a shop and waiting for your tickets turn. And yes... there are other problems like lock files not being deleted by crashing programs but those you already have.

Comment: This seems highly relevant:  https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2857.pdf: "The C11 standard introduced normative wording standardising fopen(’x’). Unfortunately the current wording allows multiple mutually incompatible implementation semantics..."